# Find String range using String parameter

Tags: java

I have a collection of the following type:

```
class Container
{
   private String startValue;
   private String endValue;
}
```

Let's say it contains these entries...

```
{"123, "789"},
{"1", "8"},
{"9", "10"},
```

Then I want to ask the collection to give me all entries which satisfy the predicate between start and end values of each Container, such as the String "5" parameter would return the two first entries above (but not the last one) whereas "9" would only return the first one (and so on).

It should behave as SQL BETWEEN operator on a VARCHAR column.

Changing type from String is not an option. Changing data structure is not an issue.

Performance is also a very importan here. The data structure is rarely changed, but retrieval is very common. A bit extra space taken if speed can be gained is also fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: `satisfy the predicate between start and end values of each Container`. can you please explain it a bit?

Comment: How does "9" return the first entry?  What is the logic here?

Comment: @DavidWallace It's a lexicographic comparison not a numeric one.

Comment: So how does "9" fall between "123" and "789"?

Comment: @DavidWallace Oops. I think my brain automatically corrected it to the last one.

Comment: Oops, example got past my mental tests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement *"Interval search tree"* using **red-black BST**.

http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/92search/
https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/algs4partI/slides%2F99GeometricSearch.pdf

Find all elements will cost `R*logN`, where `R` - number of elements to return, `N` - number of all elements.

Answer (score 2):

Add this method to the `Container` class

```
public boolean contains(String argument) {
    return argument != null && startValue.compareTo(argument) <= 0 && endValue.compareTo(argument) >= 0;
}
```

Then iterate through your collection, calling `contains` on each element.

Answer (score 1):

Well... without Integer conversion and change the structure...

You can use stringToCompare.compareTo(str) to compare Strings.

Or, you can use a fixed array of Strings like {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"}. So, you can split the Strings startValue and endValue, getting character by character and verifying the index (a int) in your array. With this int value you can do some comparisons.